# How to Display the Javascript Navigation menu On the top of the Flash in all Major Browsers

Tags: jquery, css, flash

My site has a jQuery drop-down navigation menu and that is displayed beneath the Flash. How can I display the navigation menu above the Flash object? I tried with setting  `wmode="transparent"` but it is not work. Please provide some help to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

try the CSS z-index property

```
flash-div
{
 z-index:-1;
}
```